# What I can use subquery instead for search MAX()?

Tags: mysql

I have table, 'master_log', where I store all data from all action. Each records is connected together by 'm_id':

```
m_id | value_type_id | value
------------------------------------------
1    | room          | ONE
1    | temperature   | 23
1    | humidity      | 55
1    | timestamp     | 2016-11-01 00:00:01
2    | room          | TWO
2    | timestamp     | 2016-11-01 00:10:51
2    | temperature   | 24
3    | room          | ONE
3    | temperature   | 24
3    | timestamp     | 2016-11-01 00:18:24
------------------------------------------
```

I need the maximum temperature from room ONE. The query that I use now is here:

```
SELECT MAX(value)
FROM master_log
WHERE value_type_id = 'temperature'
    AND m_id IN (SELECT m_id
                    FROM master_log
                    WHERE value = 'ONE')
```

When I start measuring, the query is quick, but now with millions of records it is not too quick, and I looking for the quickest method. Any idea please?

Comment: it's difficult to provide a faster solution without having more insight into the table structure (indices etc). Please attach the result of an `EXPLAIN <YOURQUERY>`-query here for us to help you. An *idea* would be to replace the subquery by a `JOIN`, but i am not sure if it would be faster than your query (`SELECT
  MAX(l2.value)
FROM
  master_log l1 JOIN master_log l2 ON (l1.m_id = l2.m_id)
WHERE
  l1.value_type_id = 'ROOM' AND l1.value = 'ONE' AND 
  l2.value_type_id = 'temperature'`)

Comment: yes, join is what i would like instead subquery. firstly i need select all m_id where is room one and second i need from this m_id select only temperature and count max(). what i dont understand is join with only one table.

Comment: thanks Martin Schneider for your query with JOIN, it is fork fast as mad, my query with subquery need 10s, your query with join need 0.4s. Perfect, again one step for my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT m_id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN value_type_id = 'room' THEN value END) room
     , MAX(CASE WHEN value_type_id = 'temperature' THEN value END) temperature
     , MAX(CASE WHEN value_type_id = 'humidity' THEN value END) humidity
     , MAX(CASE WHEN value_type_id = 'timestamp' THEN value END) timestamp
  FROM master_log 
 GROUP 
    BY m_id 
HAVING room = 'ONE' 
 ORDER 
    BY temperature DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```

... but, appropriately indexed, Martin's solution will be faster